# Redirect for some pages and deny access for others?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-4.0

I'm using forms authentication.

In the root web.config there's ...

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Auth/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/Search.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

... so if an unauthenticated user is denied access, by a entry like the following in the web.config of a subfolder ...

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

... then the not-logged-in user is redirected to the Login.aspx page.

---

**First question**

If an unauthenticated users requests some (but not all) pages, or requests files from one sub-folder (but not another), I want to deny access by returning HTTP 403 instead of redirecting them (HTTP 302) to the login page.

How can I do that? Currently unauthenticated users are invariably redirected to the Login page, instead of being simply denied access.

---

**Second question**

I'm also using 'role-based' privileges, for example I have a role named Supervisors.

Access to certain folders is intended only for supervisors so those folders have a web config like

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Supervisor"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

If an authenticated (logged-in) user without the Supervisor role attempts access, they too are redirected to the Login page (although they're already logged-in).

Can I change that, somehow (e.g. to return HTTP 403, or to redirect to some other failure page)?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do this manually by creating a Procedure which will run on Page_Init

```
Public Shared Sub CheckAccess()
If My.User.IsAuthenticated And (Condition Here) Then
Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx")
End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Init (sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PageInit
CheckAccess()
End Sub
```

Comment: Some of the files that I want to deny access to (by returning HTTP 403) are image files, PNG files, which have no Page_Init.

Comment: You should separate the files in different folders and set their access control in web.config

Comment: I did that (as explained in the OP) but the files in forbidden directories redirect (HTTP 302) to the Login page, what I asked is whether some of them could by access denied (HTTP 403) instead.